# My ASP.NET MVC application doesn't display videos

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a ASP.NET MVC application, and I it doesn't display any videos. I am trying to use VenoBox for stylizing my video gallery as seen in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrvWHfH5pm0

VenoBox is a package that lets you stylize groups of videos, images, iframes etc. But my view does not display anything to the screen. I have a model called "Video' where I memorize the video id and url to a database, and I send those videos in a list to my view. When using iframe for embedded videos, my videos are displaying well to the screen, but I still want to stylize my gallery with VenoBox, so I have to use "< a >" links instead of iframe, and it doesn't work.
Here is my View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<section class="content__section">

    @foreach (var video in Model)
    {
        <div class="video">
            <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="video" data-gall="myGallery" href="@video.Url"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></a>
        </div>
    }
</section>

@section scripts{
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.venobox').venobox({
                    closeColor: '#f4f4f4',
                    spinColor: '#f4f4f4',
                    closeBackground: '#17191D',
                    overlayColor: 'rgba(25,25,29,0.8)'
                });
            });
        </script>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
    }
```

Here is a link to the VenoBox website:
https://veno.es/venobox/
In bundles/lib I have saved the scripts from VenoBox. I am also using Chrome for visualizing my project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your model is null.

Try this way.

```
@model YourModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<section class="content__section">

    @foreach (var video in Model)
    {
        <div class="video">
            <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="video" data-gall="myGallery" href="@video.Url"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></a>
        </div>
    }
</section>

@section scripts{
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.venobox').venobox({
                    closeColor: '#f4f4f4',
                    spinColor: '#f4f4f4',
                    closeBackground: '#17191D',
                    overlayColor: 'rgba(25,25,29,0.8)'
                });
            });
        </script>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
    }
```

the video variable will be more meaningful this way.

Comment: I am sorry, but it still doesn't work. And my model is not null, as I said it displays the videos with "iframe". I tried `<iframe width="560" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + @video.VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></iframe>` and it works, but doesn't stylize it the way I want.